# UB: Destructor prodecues side-effect the program depends on, but not explicitly called

Tags: c++, destructor, undefined-behavior

Could you give an example of such undefined behavior? I mean, there is a quote from 3.8/4:

> For an object of a class type with a non-trivial destructor, the
>   program is not required to call the destructor explicitly before the
>   storage which the object occupies is reused or released; however, if
>   **there is no explicit call to the destructor** or if a **delete-expression**
>   (5.3.5) **is not used to release the storage**, the destructor shall not
>   be implicitly called and any program that depends on the side effects
>   produced by the destructor **has undefined behavior**.

I've been trying to invent my own example, but I've doubts about it. I think one does not properly reflect the rule I cited.

The code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

struct A
{
    ~A()
    {
        cout << "~A" << endl; //side-effect
    }

    A()
    { 
        cout << "A()" << endl;
    }
};

A *a = new A;


int main()
{
    //Prints A()
    //Is such behavior undefined?
}
```

The programm doesn't call destructor or `operator delete` explicitly. So, it must have UB. But it is strange if the programm has UB, because there is no explicitly destructor call and there is memory leak. Does memory leak produce UB?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24137427/1505939) specifically

Comment: Also relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9971559/why-is-not-deleting-an-object-that-has-a-destructor-with-a-side-effect-undefined

Comment: @Brian good find, [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24137006/does-a-memory-leak-cause-undefined-behaviour) should have been merged with that, rather than the memory leak one .